# Spacing & sizing columns using Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I'm working on a project and I'm having some trouble getting everything to line up correctly with the right spacing. What should I do (using the col class and bootstrap 4 exclusively, no CSS) to get this to work?

Ive tried multiple margin spacing (e.g ml-md-4) and offsetting (e.g offset-md-1) and nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Columns have padding to create the gutter (spacing between columns). Therefore, the background colors will blends together unless you put the background on the contents of the columns. Also, use `col-md-6` not `col-md-5`...

```
<section class="row">
        <div class="col-12 mb-3">
            <div class="bg-info" style="height: 175px;"></div>
        </div>
        <!-- one -->
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 mb-3">
            <div class="bg-info" style="height: 100px;"></div>
        </div>
        <!-- two -->
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 mb-md-4 mb-3">
            <div class="bg-info" style="height: 100px;"></div>
        </div>
        <!-- three -->
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 mb-3">
            <div class="bg-info" style="height: 100px;"></div>
        </div>
        <!-- four -->
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 mb-3">
            <div class="bg-info" style="height: 100px;"></div>
        </div>
</section>
```

https://www.codeply.com/p/QTN0GCfLbc